# За что отвечает свойство prototype после имени класса?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Не могу самостоятельно разобраться с свойством prototype, есть код:

```
<script>
    var Person = function(name){
        this.name = name;
    };

    var dev = function(name){
        Person.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    dev.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

    console.log(Person.prototype); // выведет Object {} 
    console.log(dev.prototype); // почему здесь тоже Object, a не Person 
</script>
```

не понятно почему свойство **prototype** класса **dev** указывает не на класс **Person**, а на **Object**. Я сначала подумал что это ссылка на прототип класса, но видимо это не так. Объясните что значит свойство **prototype** после имени класса.

Comment: разница в выводе может зависеть от реализации консоли в браузере

Answer (score 1):

[Читаем, вникаем, находим ответ.](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype)

Свойство `prototype` конструктора указывает на прототип объекта, который конструктор вернёт при вызове его через `new`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P. S. Хром любезно вывел имя, но другие (лиса, например) этого не сделают, только объекты встроенных конструкторов имеют имя. Созданные разработчиком объекты не имеют подобных имён. Но не смотря на то, что выводят в консоли браузеры, объект везде один.

Comment: странно но у меня firebug вторым сообщением в консоль выдает Object {}

Comment: _Свойство prototype конструктора указывает на объект, который конструктор вернёт при вызове его через new._ - какое-то странное описание, оно же совсем не на это указывает

Comment: Только объекты встроенных конструкторов имеют имя. Созданные разработчиком объекты не имеют подобных имён.

Comment: @Grundy, когда-то в учебнике прочитал что именно это оно и делает, за саму ссылку на прототип отвечает свойство `__proto__`, которое вроде как должно быть скрыто, но постоянно вижу открытое для записи. И на практике данное определение у меня всегда сходилось, просветите же меня и остальное сообщество своим, верным определением, пожалуйста!

Comment: @Other, конструктор потому и конструктор, что возвращает _новый_ объект, а не прототип.

Comment: @Grundy, "Чтобы новым объектам автоматически ставить прототип, конструктору ставится свойство prototype.

При создании объекта через new, в его прототип __proto__ записывается ссылка из prototype функции-конструктора."

Comment: @Other, _При создании объекта через new, в его прототип proto записывается ссылка из prototype_ и _Свойство prototype конструктора указывает на объект, который конструктор вернёт при вызове его через new._ - как-то вообще разное говорят, первое говорит, что запишется в свойство, а второе - вернет объект

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39183/discussion-between-other-and-grundy).